# How to extract route GPX from a Google Maps route?

Tags: google-maps, gpx

My objective is to extract a route which some user would have created on Google Maps into a GPX file containing latitude longitudes for further use in other apps.

The route will be shared via a link like this - https://goo.gl/maps/HcikiDXFwN2coeFN8

Interestingly, this app is already doing what I want to do - https://mapstogpx.com/ and https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input?convert_format=gpx. I just want to know how they are doing it so that I can emulate it for my own needs.

Since both the tools I've mentioned also require providing a Google Maps API key with the directions API enabled, my initial guess is that these tools first parse the webpage for the waypoints and then use those waypoints in a Directions API call to get all the route trackpoints.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in the "data" param in the expanded url for the google maps route link.

Lets take this URL for example - https://goo.gl/maps/zrcP5gL1cd2AHGoq8

This expands to [https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Eiffel+Tower,+Paris,+France/Palais+Garnier,+Pl.+de+l'Op%C3%A9ra,+75009+Paris,+France/@48.8606129,2.2961092,14z/am=t/data=!4m29!4m28!1m20!1m1!1s0x47e6701f7e8337b5:0xa2cb58dd28914524!2m2!1d2.2930458!2d48.8560934!3m4!1m2!1d2.3122286!2d48.8490916!3s0x47e6702fa62d0bc5:0xd2d94ed604f2e5a0!3m4!1m2!1d2.3035972!2d48.8729816!3s0x47e66fc1755cf609:0x3c5040f902b41a5f!3m4!1m2!1d2.3235117!2d48.8581242!3s0x47e66e2ac3bca3ed:0x1c289763e3096e61!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66e30d4668339:0xa9abf21c286d0767!2m2!1d2.3316014!2d48.8719697!3e0](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Eiffel+Tower,+Paris,+France/Palais+Garnier,+Pl.+de+l%27Op%C3%A9ra,+75009+Paris,+France/@48.8606129,2.2961092,14z/am=t/data=!4m29!4m28!1m20!1m1!1s0x47e6701f7e8337b5:0xa2cb58dd28914524!2m2!1d2.2930458!2d48.8560934!3m4!1m2!1d2.3122286!2d48.8490916!3s0x47e6702fa62d0bc5:0xd2d94ed604f2e5a0!3m4!1m2!1d2.3035972!2d48.8729816!3s0x47e66fc1755cf609:0x3c5040f902b41a5f!3m4!1m2!1d2.3235117!2d48.8581242!3s0x47e66e2ac3bca3ed:0x1c289763e3096e61!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66e30d4668339:0xa9abf21c286d0767!2m2!1d2.3316014!2d48.8719697!3e0)

On closer examination, you will see that the data param has lat-lng coordinates embedded in it. For example this
`!1d2.2930458!2d48.8560934` or `!1d2.3122286!2d48.8490916`. These are longitude latitude pairs representing various waypoints on the route. The longitude always starts with `!1d` and ends with `!2d` and the latitude starts with `!2d` and ends with `!3`.

Here is a small kotlin method to extract all the coordinates :

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191093/3090120
fun String?.indexesOf(pat: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = true): List<Int> =
        pat.toRegex(if (ignoreCase) setOf(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE) else emptySet())
                .findAll(this ?: "")
                .map { it.range.first }
                .toList()

fun extractCoordinates(expandedUrl: String): List<LatLng> {
    val latLngList = arrayListOf<LatLng>()
    val indexes = expandedUrl.indexesOf("!1d")

    indexes.forEach {
        val coordinatesStr = expandedUrl.substring(it + 3).substringBefore("!3").split("!2d")
        latLngList.add(LatLng(coordinatesStr[1].toDouble(), coordinatesStr[0].toDouble()))
    }

    return latLngList
}
```

The result with this string would be
`[lat/lng: (48.8560934,2.2930458), lat/lng: (48.8490916,2.3122286), lat/lng: (48.8729816,2.3035972), lat/lng: (48.8581242,2.3235117), lat/lng: (48.8719697,2.3316014)]`

Once we have all the lat-lng pairs we can simply fire off a Google Maps Directions API call and recreate the route in the link and export it as a GPX file.